# Assign someone to/in a city/country

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, idiomatic-language, prepositional-verbs

Let's say an employee was assigned to work in a particular district/city/country etc. Can we say that person was assigned "to" or "in" there? In the Oxford Dictionary, the definition of the usage I want to use is "to send a person to work under the authority of somebody or in a particular group". But my question is not about working in a group but working in a place like a city, country etc. where my workplace/army base etc. is. Let's say I am a public school teacher and I was sent to work at a school in a city or country called "XYZ", or maybe a neighborhood called "XYZ". Can I say either of these two sentences interchangeably?

> I was assigned in XYZ.

> I was assigned to XYZ.

**Some other example sentences:** *"I was assigned in/to Los Angeles", "I was assigned in/to Nigeria", "I was assigned in/to the Valley Neighborhood"

Are these okay with either "to" or "in", or do I have to specify the workplace instead of specifying where the work place is when I use "assign"?

Comment: _Assign_ is usually followed with _to_.

Comment: assigned in a place means that is where a person assigned you to another one to work.

Comment: @Lambie I don't understand what you mean, sorry. Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: "I was assigned **to the position** [when I was] **in Los Angeles**". Oh really? "I was assigned in Las Vegas, not LA."

Comment: @Lambie What do you think about **appoint in/at**? Should we use **"He was appointed to Los Angeles"** instead of **"He was appointed in Los Angeles"? I probably should open another topic on "appoint."

Comment: You seem to not want to understand even after two explanations. Sorry, can't do anymore for you. There are two **different things** that can be said. With **different meanings**. And **at** is wrong in any case.

Comment: @Lambie "even after two explanations." I asked a completely different question. It seems you are the one who doesn't want to understand. Thank you for your previous effort, but don't answer my questions again please.

Comment: Unlike the person who answered, I patiently explained twice how "assigned in" can in fact be used. Your second comment repeats your question again right after I explained the difference a second time. Only a saint would not fail to say something.

Answer (score 5):

**No**, "assigned in" and "assigned to" are not interchangeable. "Assigned to" is idiomatic and "assigned in" is not.

As you say, when describing *what* you were assigned, you use the preposition **to**:

> In Nigeria, I was assigned **to** the water-supply project.

And when describing *where* you were assigned, you also use **to**:

> When I joined the Peace Corps I was assigned **to** Nigeria.

If it helps, you can think of it as being a sort of shortening of "assigned **to** *working in Nigeria*," with "working in Nigeria" describing *what* you were assigned to do rather than *where* you were assigned to do it.

It is also possible to omit the preposition and say you were simply assigned [noun]:

> I was assigned mess-hall duty.

In this usage the noun is often "duty," "patrol," etc, but it can be just about anything: "I was assigned sweeping" is perfectly valid, though you could say "sweeping *duty*" as well.

---

As Lambie points out in the comments, if you really really want to do it, it is *technically* possible to use **assigned in** to specify *the place where you were at the time you received the assignment*:

> I was assigned in New York to Nigeria.

But this is awkward and confusing phrasing, and rewriting it would be better:

> In New York, I was assigned to Nigeria.
> I was assigned to Nigeria when I got to New York.

---

**Appoint** works exactly the same as I have described **assign** above.

Comment: Can we just use "assign somebody" instead of "assign somebody to/as somebody" or "assign somebody to do something". For example like, "A new teacher was assigned." Do we have to specify what he/she was assigned to? According to Oxford, we can omit that, but other dictionaries don't mention that.

Comment: That can work **if** there is sufficient context. For example: "We started the school year with Mrs. Smith, but a new teacher was assigned in October." Although "we were assigned a new teacher in October" sounds better.

Comment: @ramdomhead What do you think is wrong with "was assigned in"?

Comment: "A teacher was assigned" is a *very passive* passive-voice clause; it doesn't say who assigned the teacher, nor what (or where) the teacher was assigned (you have to go back to the first part of the sentence for context). This is the kind of passive voice people talk about when they say that the passive voice should be avoided—it allows for twisted constructions like "A bullet was fired from the policeman's gun and a bystander was killed." In contrast, "We were assigned a teacher" is still passive voice, but there is more context bundled into the clause and it sounds less awkward.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same questions about "appoint," but I need to open another topic I guess.

Comment: I was assigned in Los Angeles to New York. I was not assigned to New York in Las Vegas. I strove  mightily to explain that and was rebuffed. :) Appoint or assign work exactly the same way.